# Cell in UITableView doesn't update until selected in iOS (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I'm developing an app with Parse that has a tableview with cells containing a label that has mutual friends from Facebook, my problem is that everything thing in the table works fine but the mutual friends label, it takes long to show unless I select the row (when I select the row the number appears immediately).. Here's my code for getting the mutual friends and setting the label in the cell:

```
let facebookContext = driverobj?.objectForKey("facebookContext") as! String
let user: PFUser = PFUser.currentUser()!
let access_token = user.valueForKey("authData")?.valueForKey("facebook")?.valueForKey("access_token") as! String
let usercontexturl: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://graph.facebook.com/\(facebookContext)/mutual_friends?access_token=\(access_token)")!

let myrequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: usercontexturl)
let mysession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = mysession.dataTaskWithRequest(myrequest) { data, response, error in
        print("Task completed")
        do {
             let jsonresult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
             cell.mutualFriendsLabel?.text = (jsonresult.valueForKey("summary")?.valueForKey("total_count"))!.stringValue + " Mutual Friends"

        } catch {
             print(error)
        }
}
task.resume()
```

This code is inside cellForRowAtIndexPath method, and didSelectRowAtIndexPath method in empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The block passed to `dataTaskWithRequest` is probably not executing on the main thread which can cause these types of symptoms to appear. Try executing the UI updates to the main thread like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    cell.mutualFriendsLabel?.text = (jsonresult.valueForKey("summary")?.valueForKey("total_count"))!.stringValue + " Mutual Friends"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to update UI on main queue like this:

```
dispatch_async_(your_queue) {
    task.response {
        //handle data
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            //update UI, etc. change label text
        }
    }
}
```